# Google not indexing my site and no issues in Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index

Hi I have an IT consultancy that been up on Google for the last year or more that was indexed with no issues. Just a few weeks ago Google removed the site from their index and there seems to be no reasons why it now does not appear.

Search console doesn't show any manual actions or security issues, and URL inspection is showing that it is indexed and everything should be fine.

I recently tried hiring an SEO company to help me and their only advice was to rebrand my company and change domain to a new one,  which I thought was unacceptable.

Can anyone give me some advice or some tips to how I can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you search `site:yourdomain.com`? Do you get any results? If so, your site is indexed.

Comment: Na no results (